# Creating a string from the permutations of an ArrayBuffer[String] elements in Scala

Tags: string, scala, permutation, arraybuffer

I have

```
val a: String = "E"
val y: ArrayBuffer[String] = new ArrayBuffer("I", "G", "S")
```

I am trying to make a string, such that:

```
"(E <=> (I | G | S)) & (~I | ~G) & (~I | ~S) & (~G | ~S)"
```

Currently, for the first part of string (first clause) `(E <=> (I | G | S))`, I have this which is functional:

```
s"($a <=> (${y.mkString(" | ")}))" // & (~${y.mkString(" | ~")})"
```

For the second part, where are the permutations of elements in `y`, i.e., for `(~I | ~G) & (~I | ~S) & (~G | ~S)`, how I can improve (fix) the part within comments to create it?

I am trying to use the `y.permutations`, to create another string and then to concatenate with this one, but can it be "generated" here - within the same string in some way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your example that what you need is combinations, not permutations.

So to have a term for every pair of elements from `y` you can find all combinations of length 2 using `combinations` method. Then you can wrap each pair in brackets in the necessary format, and finally build the whole second part with `mkString`:

```
y.combinations(2).map { case Seq(a, b) => s"(~$a | ~$b)" }.mkString(" & ")
```

You can integrate this expression into the string interpolation:

```
s"($a <=> (${y.mkString(" | ")})) & ${
  y.combinations(2).map { case Seq(a, b) => s"(~$a | ~$b)" }.mkString(" & ")}"
```

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the result that I am trying to achieve. I was quite far from trying in this way :/. Thank you so much - I really mean it!